# Bounding type parameters of generic methods with interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface, generic-method

So I have 2 versions of the same method.

**Version 1:**

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) 
    {
        int count = 0; 
        for (T e : anArray)
        {
            if (e > elem)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

**Version 2:**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (T e : anArray)
        {
            if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Eclipse complains about **Version 1** because the > operator can only be used when comparing primitives, which makes sense to me.

So to fix this problem, the internet tells me to use a type parameter bounded by the Comparable interface. This is where I start to lose grasp of what's going on...

From my basic understanding of interfaces, a class that implements an interface must provide a method body for each of the methods declared in the interface.

Thus, why doesn't **Version 2** have to look like this?

```
public int compareTo(T o)
    {
        //stuff for method body
    }


    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (T e : anArray)
        {
            if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

^**I get that this isn't correct syntax**, but I just did it to illustrate my question as to why I don't have to write a method body for the method in the Comparable interface in this situation.

**Please try to keep the explanation in Layman's terms.** I've been teaching myself this stuff, so simple explanations help me understand the more technical side of topics when I research them further.

---

Sorry for the confusion, let me clarify.

Here is the code for the Comparable interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
   public int compareTo(T o);
     }
```

There is no method body for compareTo() because it's an interface. Why don't I have to manually write a body for compareTO() so I can use the interface in my countGreaterThan() method?

Is it because the interface is part of the Java Collections Framework (if that's why please explain how that works)

Here's a different situation where I create my own interface:

```
public interface Dance { //an interface
  public void boogie(int count);
}
```

and in order to implement that interface in different classes I need to write method bodies in those classes for the method in the dance interface.

```
public class theMoonwalk implements Dance {
  public void boogie(int count) {
    System.out.println("Slide " + count + " times!");
  }
  public void mJ() {
    System.out.println("Michael Jackson did this dance!");

}
public class theHustle implements Dance {
  public void boogie(int steps) {
    System.out.println("Step " + steps + " times!");
  }
}
public class theJitterBug implements Dance {
  public void boogie(int twists) {
    System.out.println("Twist " + twists + " times!");
  }
}
```

**Why don't I have to write a method body for compareTo() (because a method body is not included in the Comparable interface for compareTo() )?**

Comment: Are you asking why you don't have to write the `public int compareTo(T o)` method?

Comment: I don't get it. The class that contains the `countGreaterThan` method doesn't have to implement `Comparable`... Could you clarify what it is you're asking here?

Comment: @Patrick The generic type T must implement the `compareTo` method, not the class that contains the generic method.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type that `T` ultimately refers to has to implement `Comparable<T>`, not the class that you're declaring the type bound on.

To make it a bit simpler:  in order to use your `countGreaterThan` method, whatever objects are contained in your array and in your `elem` argument must be a `Comparable` object.

This means that an invocation like this is acceptable:

```
Integer[] foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
YourClass.countGreaterThan(foo, 2);
```

Your type is bound to `Integer`, and `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`.

This is *not* acceptable:

```
Object[] bar = {new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};
YourClass.countGreaterThan(bar, new Object());
```

Your type is bound to `Object`, and `Object` does not implement `Comparable`.  The same logic applies to a custom object that you implement; if it isn't bound to Comparable, then it's not going to be in the proper bound.